# Finding $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\sigma^2\left(\frac{\tau}{\sum_{i=1}^n1\{x_i<\tau\}}+\frac{1-\tau}{\sum_{i=1}^n1\{x_i>\tau\}}\right)$

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}[n\operatorname{var}(\hat f_\tau)]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\sigma^2\left(\frac{\tau}{\sum_{i=1}^n1\{x_i<\tau\}}+\frac{1-\tau}{\sum_{i=1}^n1\{x_i>\tau\}}\right)=?$$

The $x_i$ are known deterministic points in $(0, 1)$ and $\tau$ is between $0$ and $1$. Does this limit equal $\sigma^2$, if so what is the proof? Or does it converge to something else? The context of this problem is a bias-variance decomposition. I decomposed $R(f, \hat f)=[b(\hat f)]^2+\operatorname{var}\hat f$ and the question is asking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of nVar.

Attempt at solution:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\sigma^2 \left(\frac{\tau}{\sum_{i=1}^n1\{x_i<\tau\}}+\frac{1-\tau}{\sum_{i=1}^n1\{x_i>\tau\}}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\sigma^2\left(\frac{\tau}{n}+\frac{1-\tau}{n}\right)\,,$$ because $n$ is very large

$$=\sigma^2(\tau+1-\tau)=\sigma^2$$